# XSLT - Replace a number of chars in a string

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following string,

```
';#6;#'
```

The above string could be anything, E.g.:

```
';#1;#' or ';#2;#' , or ';#3;#' ...
```

I need to be able to replace the contents between the `'` and `'`

Is this possible using something like translate in XSLT 1.0?

Comment: You are likely to replace all the string, why not just rewriting the text like `'replace'`? Please be clearer.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of thing is quite difficult in XSLT 1.0. Take a look at the library of string-handling functions available at www.exslt.org - some of them come with XSLT implementations that you can copy into your stylesheet and call (typically as xsl:call-template).

Comment: People using XSLT 1.0 and needing _string-handling_ should live with standard additional templates included in their stylesheets and stop wandering about how to "reinvent the wheel".

Answer (score 0):

Use `substring` and `concat` functions.